# What is the difference between git revision formats refname@{n} and rev~n

Tags: git

The man page makes a distinction as follows

Quote man gitrevisions ...

> For example master@{1} is the immediate prior value of master while
>   master@{5} is the 5th prior value of master.

AND

> A suffix ~<n> to a revision parameter means the commit object that is
>   the <n>th generation grand-parent of the named commit object,
>   following only the first parents.

End quote

I understand that generalizations of these separate formats lead to different usage patterns, but the difference in terminology (e.g "prior value" vs "grand-parent") makes me think there might be some difference.

Is master@{n} the same as master~n ?

Apologies if this a frequently asked question, but this is the kind of thing it's difficult to google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not the same.  To understand why, you will have to understand the **reflog**.  Think of the reflog as a giant log table of all the commits that the branches in **your repository** used to point to ("prior value", if you will).

So that's [the reflog](http://gitolite.com/concepts/reflog.html), and it allows you to get back to past values of branches.  `master@{5}` was what master used to point at 5 events ago (whether those events were commits you made or resets of master, etc.)

The other syntax, `master^5` and `master~5`, are more what you expect.  These deal with the parents of the commit that master is currently pointing to.

Comment: Exactly—and, the reflog records changes to `HEAD` too.  As a more concrete example, suppose you `git checkout master~5` and then `git checkout master`.  Now `git rev-parse HEAD@{1}` and `git rev-parse master~5` show the same SHA1 (because `checkout` updates `HEAD`).  `HEAD@{0}` and `master` likewise name the same commit.